# How can I disable editing of a list item in a SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, restriction

So i have a list on Sharepoint.
The point of the list is that only administrators can edit the documents and upload them. The rest of the users are going to be able to see the document exmpl. Title ( Ok so i hid couple of columns and made it so that only the name of the file is shown, but not the link to the document).

The issue is that users can select the item and edit them (I don't wnat that), they can also download them (not exceptable either).

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. What are the users permissions? You mentioned that they can edit documents so they might have contribute permissions. Check the permissions by going to the Ribbon > Library tab > Library Permissions. Users need to have at least Contribute/Edit permissions to be able to edit documents in SharePoint.
2. Who are the members of the Contribute group? Is "Everyone" added there? If so, every user will be able to edit documents.
3. Is the library inheriting permissions from the site? One possible solution (not great) is to break the library inheritance and grant users/SharePoint group with Read-Only/View permission.
4. Is there any custom permission level granting the users ability to Edit documents? -> "https://yoursite/_layouts/15/role.aspx" will show you what permission level you have on that Site Collection.

[Useful MS Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782) - **Edit and manage permissions for a SharePoint list or library**